# How to attach ajax event to composite component?

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2, composite-component

I have the following composite component (<v2:inputText2>)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:composite="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich">

<!-- INTERFACE -->
<composite:interface>
    <composite:attribute name="baseId" required="true" />
    <composite:attribute name="size" required="true" />
    <composite:attribute name="value" required="true" />
  <composite:attribute name="align" required="false" default="" />
  <composite:attribute name="label" required="false" default="" />
  <composite:attribute name="labelStyle" required="false" default="" />
    <composite:attribute name="disabled" required="false" default="false" />
    <composite:attribute name="required" required="false" default="false" />
    <composite:attribute name="inputStyle" required="false" default="" />
    <composite:editableValueHolder name="inTxt" />
</composite:interface>

<!-- IMPLEMENTATION -->
<composite:implementation>
    <h:panelGroup id="#{cc.attrs.baseId}Dec">
        <table class="decTable" style="align:#{cc.attrs.align};" border="1">
            <tr>
                <td class="labelSize" style="vertical-align: middle;">
                  <h:outputLabel
                        id="#{cc.attrs.baseId}Lbl" for="#{cc.attrs.baseId}"
                        value="#{cc.attrs.label}" style="#{cc.attrs.labelStyle}" /></td>

                <td width="#{cc.attrs.size}">
                  <h:inputText
                        id="inTxt" value="#{cc.attrs.value}"
                        disabled="#{cc.attrs.disabled}"
                        style="width: 99%; #{cc.attrs.inputStyle}"
                        required="#{cc.attrs.required}">
                        <!-- composite:insertChildren / -->
                    </h:inputText></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><h:panelGroup id="#{cc.attrs.baseId}Error">
                        <rich:message for="#{cc.attrs.baseid}">
                            <rich:tooltip id="#{cc.attrs.baseId}TT" styleClass="validError">
                                <rich:message id="#{cc.attrs.baseId}TTMsg"
                                    for="#{cc.attrs.baseId}" showDetail="false" showSummary="true" />
                            </rich:tooltip>
                        </rich:message>
                    </h:panelGroup></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </h:panelGroup>
</composite:implementation>

</html>
```

In the following Fragment, I want to add an <a4j:ajax> event to this component using like this:

```
    <rich:panel style="width:560px;">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Combobox "></h:outputText>
        </f:facet>
        <v2:inputText2 size="300px" baseId="baseId_txt" id="txt" label="Text:"
            value="#{testInput2.value}">
            <a4j:ajax event="change" render="dbgText"/>
        </v2:inputText2>

        <h:outputText value="#{testInput2.value}" id="dbgText"/>
    </rich:panel>
    <aj4:commandButton id="cmdOK" value="Ok"
        action="#{testInput2.cmdOk ()}" render="@form" />
```

When I call the Testpage, then I get the following Error:

```
testInput2.xhtml @23,48 <a4j:ajax> Error: enclosing composite component does not support event change
```

How can I solve the problem?

The Ajax-Event should trigger a UI-Bean-Methode.

Thanks 
Ronald

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to register it as client behavior in composite's interface.

```
<cc:interface>
    ...
    <cc:clientBehavior name="clientEvent" targets="inputId" event="valueChange" />
</cc:interface>
<cc:implementation>
    ...
    <h:inputText id="inputId" ... />
</cc:implementation>
```

- `name`: The custom event name as you would specify in composite's client. Can be the same as the actual event name. Can be a customized one. It's all free to your choice.
- `targets`: The composite implementation relative client ID of the target component on which the actual client behavior should be attached.
- `event`: The actual event name which the actual client behavior should be listening. Note that the default event of `EditableValueHolder` components is `valueChange` and not `change`. You can for text input fields keep using `change` if you want.

With the above declaration example, you can use it in template client as below:

```
<my:composite ...>
    <f:ajax event="clientEvent" ... />
</my:composite>
```

After this, you'll face a second but unrelated problem which is already asked and answered here: [<f:ajax render> not working via <composite:clientBehavior>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23804002/fajax-render-not-working-via-compositeclientbehavior).

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, that composite can better be a tagfile. And, that HTML table markup is not Web 2.0.