# <f:ajax> not working with composite component

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2, composite-component

```
<cc:interface componentType="inputAutoComplete">
    <cc:attribute name="reRender" type="java.lang.String" shortDescription="Provide The ids of the component to be refreshed"></cc:attribute>
    <cc:attribute name="baseURL" type="java.lang.String" shortDescription="Provide service method name of frontController API" />
    <cc:attribute name="labelValue" required="true" shortDescription="This is the binding value for label similar to drop down label(ItemLable).If key not present ,Then label is must.It will be considered as key "/>
    <cc:attribute name="keyValue"  shortDescription="This is the binding value for label similar to drop down key(ItemKey) .Its a hidden field"/>
    <cc:attribute name="keyType" type="java.lang.String" shortDescription="The value has to be KEY or KEYVALUE . It defines weather labelValue is key or label"/>
    <cc:attribute name="isRequired" type="java.lang.String"/>
    <cc:attribute name="datatype" type="java.lang.String" required="true" shortDescription="Data type value only to be dynamic or static"/>
    <cc:attribute name="varname" type="java.lang.String" shortDescription="If It is a static json list , then varname is must"/>
    <cc:attribute name="manageBeanName" shortDescription="If static list to be prepared from ManagedBean then ManagedBean name is must"/>
    <cc:attribute name="manageBeanMethodName" type="java.lang.String" shortDescription="If static list to be prepared from ManagedBean then ManagedBean method name is must and method should return String only as return type"/>
    <cc:attribute name="onchange" />
    <cc:editableValueHolder name="inTxt" />
    <cc:clientBehavior name="clientEvent" targets="inTxt" event="change" />
</cc:interface>
<cc:implementation>


        <h:inputText id="intext" value="#{cc.attrs.labelValue}" binding="#{cc.userInputbinding}" 
        onchange="#{cc.attrs.onchange}">
        <cc:insertChildren />
        </h:inputText>
        <p style="display: none;">THIS VALUE IS INVALID</p> 
        <h:inputText style="display:none" styleClass="hiddenClass" value="#{cc.attrs.keyValue}" />
        <h:panelGroup rendered="#{cc.includeJsonInPage}">

        </h:panelGroup>
        <f:param name="baseURL" value="#{cc.attrs.baseURL}"/>
        <f:param name="datatype" value="#{cc.attrs.datatype}"/>
        <f:param name="varname" value="#{cc.attrs.varname}"/>
        <f:param name="manageBeanName" value="#{cc.attrs.manageBeanName}"/>
        <f:param name="manageBeanMethodName" value="#{cc.attrs.manageBeanMethodName}"/>
        <f:param name="keyType" value="#{cc.attrs.keyType}"/>
        <f:param name="isRequired" value="#{cc.attrs.isRequired}"/>
        <f:param name="keyValue" value="#{cc.attrs.keyValue}"/>
</cc:implementation>
```

Implementation --

```
        <h:panelGroup id="pnlGrp_editCustomerGroupManageLocal">
        <asset:inputAutoComplete datatype="static" labelValue="abcd"  id="samleAuto" varname="availableTags"    >

                <f:ajax event="clientEvent" onevent="alert('sfdksd')"></f:ajax>
                </asset:inputAutoComplete>
                </h:panelGroup>
```

The above is the implementation of composite component . I am not able to trigger ajax event from inside the component.
Please help me to know what could be the possible issue with the code .

Comment: Please have a look this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31912815/how-to-attach-ajax-event-to-composite-component

Comment: I have seen that post . I have tried to follow that also . It still doesn't work.

Comment: If you use PrimeFaces you could try with p:ajax

Comment: no input with name "inTxt". Make sure your example is at minimum valid